# Как выделить слова "спасибо" и т.п. ?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли кавычки и (или) заглавная буква?

1. Ты не забыл сказать тёте "здравствуйте" / "спасибо"  ?
2. И я говорю вам всем: большое спасибо!
3. Даже "спасибо" не сказал!
4. Ушел, не сказав "спасибо".

Answer (score 2):

Этот случай не описан в справочниках. Здесь надо опираться на практику письма. Обычно в таких случаях ставят кавычки, а само слово пишут  со строчной.

Вот ответ Грамоты.ру.

Вопрос № 229351

> Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, как следует писать предложение "скажите целлюлиту (?)прощай(?)". Надо ли обязательно брать "прощай" в кавычки, а также писать ли это слово с прописной буквы, если закавычивать? Спасибо.
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Это сложный случай, не рассмотренный в современных справочниках по русскому языку. Пишут как с кавычками, так и без них (в обоих случаях с маленькой буквы). На наш взгляд, в этом случае лучше ставить кавычки: *скажите целлюлиту «прощай»*.

Answer (score 2):

Ты не забыл сказать тёте "здравствуйте" / "спасибо" ?

И я говорю вам всем: большое спасибо!

Даже "спасибо" не сказал!

Ушел, не сказав "спасибо".

Все знаки расставлены правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Ты не забыл сказать тёте "здравствуйте" / "спасибо" ?

И я говорю вам всем: большое спасибо!

Даже спасибо не сказал!

Ушел, не сказав спасибо.

---

Думаю, так будет лучше всего.

А вот *скажите целлюлиту «прощай»* — тут я согласен с "Грамотой", лучше в кавычках.

Answer (score 1):

Ты не забыл сказать тёте "здравствуйте" / "спасибо"? И я говорю вам всем: большое спасибо!

Даже "спасибо" не сказал! Ушел, не сказав "спасибо" (возможны оба варианта)

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Как считает Грамота.ру, "это сложный случай, не рассмотренный в современных справочниках по русскому языку".  Вот книжные люди, просто ни шагу без справочника! Пока не рассмотрит комиссия, и писать уже нельзя.

Однако это именно тот случай, когда не правила надо составлять и учить, а решать задачу по следующему принципу: определите грамматику и  выбирайте знак.

А синтаксис предложений с  вежливыми словами очень разный, и в одних случаях подходит БСП, в других - прямая речь в разных вариантах (классическая, упрощенная).

И было бы очень правильно **обозначить устойчивое выражение "сказать спасибо" (=поблагодарить) и употреблять "спасибо" без кавычек** на законных основаниях, наряду с другими вариантами.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Блеснула вспышка, щелкнул аппарат, и фотограф сказал: «Спасибо». [И. А. Ильф, Е. П. Петров. - Ну вот ты арбуз поел, почему не сказал "спасибо"? [Виктор Драгунский. Англичанин Павля).

Он сказал «спасибо» и пригласил меня в свой кабинет. Она дала мне пройти, и я сказал: «Спасибо». Он взял, сказал спасибо и широко улыбнулся. Адвокат список сверил. Сказал «спасибо» и «гуд-бай». Нахальный такой адвокат.

А раньше кавычки не ставили

Я сказал спасибо и побожился, что не скажу. [Ф. М. Решетников. Горнозаводские люди (1863)] Васюха сам попробовал и сам увидел, что дедушка говорит правду; сказал спасибо, поклонился [С. Т. Аксаков. Семейная хроника (1856). У нас никто не в состоянии исследовать огромное создание Карамзина ― зато никто не сказал спасибо человеку, уединившемуся в ученый кабинет... [А. С. Пушкин.

Comment: Вера, вы говорите, что синтаксис разный, и в то же время говорите, что правильно писать без кавычек. Как понять?

Comment: Я согласен, что синтаксис разный. Но есть спорные случаи. Надо сказать ''спасибо" ,какой здесь синтаксис?

Comment: Я думаю, что "сказать спасибо" - это устойчивое выражение со значением "поблагодарить". "Никто не сказал спасибо" - это значит "никто не поблагодарил". Но есть тексты, где автору удобно обозначить спасибо  как обычную прямую речь. Поэтому у автора есть выбор, если грамматика связана с письмом, но при этом он должен чувствовать и уметь определять эту грамматику.